# utilise a sub-array as indexes for additional searches in a worksheet function?

Tags: excel, indexing, rows, sub-array

Related post:"How do you extract a subarray from an array in a worksheet function?" I cannot comment or reply to that post.

I have a data array of five columns (5000 records), and an NCriteria array of six columns (400 records).
The following abridged formula is used to return the matching row number from the array, NCriteria, for every data record:

```
= MATCH(TRUE, INDEX(
    COUNTIFS(
        J2, INDEX(NCriteria,,2),
        K2, INDEX(NCriteria,,3),
        K2, INDEX(NCriteria,,4),
        M2, INDEX(NCriteria,,6)
    )
    <>0,)
,0)
```

Sample data:

```
Account[J], Date[K],        Description[M]

xxx9608,    30/06/2015,     Wdl ATM CBA ATM

Sample NCriteria:

Account[col2],  date[col3],         date[col4],         description[col6]

<>"",   >=11/12/2013,   <=12/1/2014,    *BUNNINGS*;

xxx9608,    >=14/06/2013,   <=30/06/2015,   Wdl*;
```

This construct is flexible, but slow in Excel. I can extract a sub list of matching rows from NCriteria for Description `[M]` alone as:
`{375, 150, 149}`. 
Question is, how can I use this sub-array of row numbers as indexes for additional searches of matches for `[J]`, `[K]`, etc.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Comment: The line is fuzzy, but above a certain threshold of complexity VBA becomes such a natural tool that avoiding it in favor of clever hacks with array formulas becomes counter-productive. I suspect that you have crossed than threshold.

Comment: Thanks John, appreciate the observation, but I do not want to do VBA.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek. Thanks for cleaning up the posting.

Comment: @johncoleman. I believe the construct is clear concise and powerful. I just cannot implement an efficient sub-array of non contiguous references to the index(NCriteria...) construct.